# My python code is not working

Tags: python, tkinter

This simple code is not working.

I mean its running without errors but
is not showing any gui window for text entry.

```
from Tkinter import *    
from tkMessageBox import *

root=Tk()   
Label(root,text="first").grid(row=0)    
Label(root,text="second").grid(row=2)    
e1=Entry(root)    
e1.grid(row=0,column=2)    
e2=Entry(root)    
e2.grid(row=2,column=3)



def info():    
    s=showinfo(title="wish",message=e1.get()+''+"welcome to python")



Button(root,text="ok",command=info).pack()    
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `grid` and `pack` on two widgets owned by the same parent. This causes the geometry manager to loop forever.

Change your Button positioning to:

```
Button(root,text="ok",command=info).grid(row=3, column=0)
```

(or whatever row/column you want it to be in).

Result:

[image]